# D3 V6 and JavaScript - GeoJSON fill is "spilling" outside of path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

Creating a map using D3 V6, showing educational attainment by county. I have a counties.topojson and csvData.csv which are loaded:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(d3.csv("data/csvData.csv")); //load attributes from csv
promises.push(d3.json("data/counties.topojson")); //load background spatial data

Promise.all(promises).then(callback);
```

and in a callback function assigned to variables `csvData` and `counties`. The `counties` are then translated using:

```
miCounties = topojson.feature(counties, counties.objects.collection).features;
```

The `csvData` is joined to the county data, and the join is confirmed in `console.log(joinedCounties)`, within the callback function `setEnumerationUnits()` is called (where `colorScale` is quantile scale based on an array created from the `csvData` and `map` is the `SVG` element:

```
function setEnumerationUnits(joinedCounties,map,path,colorScale){
var counties = map.selectAll(".counties")
    .data(joinedCounties)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d){
        return "counties " + d.properties.NAME;
    })
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return choropleth(d.properties, colorScale);
     })
```

I should also mention adding "fill" to the `.counties` class in CSS also creates the "spilling". I have checked the topojson in QGIS and Pro, which both appear normal. I have also tried a second source of data with the same results.
Here is the result:

[image: image of faulted map]

Here is what is looks like without styling, no fill, just stroke defined in CSS:

[image: counties without styling or fill]

I receive no errors in the console. I appreciate any help anyone can give! Thanks!

Thank you! The turf.rewind worked!!

here's what I added to make it work (after installing turf library):

```
        miCounties.forEach(function(feature){
        feature.geometry = turf.rewind(feature.geometry, {reverse:true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or more of your GeoJSON entries are the wrong way around. The values are correct, but they are in the wrong order. `d3-geo` generally expects [GeoJSON features to be clockwise](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo):

> Spherical polygons also require a winding order convention to determine which side of the polygon is the inside: the exterior ring for polygons smaller than a hemisphere must be clockwise, while the exterior ring for polygons larger than a hemisphere must be anticlockwise.

You can fix the winding of your data using a plugin or tool like [`turf`](https://turfjs.org/), which you can use to ["rewind"](https://turfjs.org/docs/#rewind) your shapes - though you should use the `reverse: true` option.

Comment: Thank you, this saved a lot of time...